# Working with OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, openxml

I am passing XML to SQL Server stored procedure and trying it to store in `#temp` table.

The stored procedure is given below:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i OUTPUT  
,@XMLDOC  

 SELECT Id  
 ,UserId  
 ,ModifiedOn  
 ,ModifiedBy  
 ,ModifiedIp  
 ,DetailId
INTO #temp  
FROM OPENXML(@i, '/Root/Rec/Detail', 1) WITH (  
id INT '../@Id'  
,UserId INT '../@UserId'  
,ModifiedOn DATETIME '../@ModifiedOn'  
,ModifiedBy INT '../@ModifiedBy'  
,ModifiedIp VARCHAR(15) '../@ModifiedIp'  
,DetailId INT '@DetailId' 

)  

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @i  

select * from #temp
```

And the sample of XML:

```
<root>
    <rec id="I001" userid="316" modifiedon="9/10/2016 02:33:56 PM" modifiedby="316" modifiedip="::1" UserDetail="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dto.UserDetail]">
    </rec>
</root>
```

When the XML contains child nodes (`detail`), this SP will work fine. If I don't have child nodes - it will not work. Could you point out where I went wrong?

Comment: When the xml contains child nodes, this sp will work fine. If I don't have  child nodes, it will not work

Comment: This looks like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The whole question cries "wrong approach!". First of all: `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used anymore. There are much better methods. Secondly, if you want to deal with `XML`, you should use the appropriate datatype, not `VARCHAR(MAX)` (which is even worse as it will not deal with special characters correctly). I suggest you: Start a new question. Explain what you have, explain what you want and what you've tried so far. Give an example and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally rewrite answer:

```
DECLARE @i int,
        @XMLDOC VARCHAR(max)= "INPUT XML"

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i OUTPUT  
,@XMLDOC  

SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (
SELECT  m.Id,
        m.UserId,
        m.ModifiedOn,
        m.ModifiedBy,  
        m.ModifiedIp,  
        COALESCE(det.DetailId, -1) as DetailId
FROM OPENXML(@i, '/root/rec', 1) WITH (  
        id INT '@availabilityid',  
        UserId INT '@userid',  
        ModifiedOn DATETIME '@modifiedon',
        ModifiedBy INT '@modifiedby',  
        ModifiedIp VARCHAR(15) '@modifiedip'
) as m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  Id,
            DetailId
    FROM OPENXML(@i, '/root/rec/userturnarounddetail', 1) WITH (  
            id INT '../@availabilityid',
            DetailId INT '@availabilitydetailid' 
            )
    ) as det
    ON m.id =det.id
) p


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @i  

select * from #temp
```

Output:

```
Id      UserId  ModifiedOn              ModifiedBy  ModifiedIp  DetailId
113367  316     2016-09-11 11:01:09.000 316         ::1         300100
0       316     2016-09-11 11:01:11.000 316         ::1         -1
```

**EDIT**

Example with `.nodes` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx). It is available since SQL Server 2008.

```
DECLARE @XMLDOC xml 

SELECT @XMLDOC = 
'<root>
    <rec id="I001" userid="316" modifiedon="9/10/2016 02:33:56 PM" modifiedby="316" modifiedip="::1" UserDetail="System.Collections.Generic.List1[Dto.UserDetail]">
    </rec>
</root>'

SELECT  ISNULL(d.f.value('@id','nvarchar(15)'),d.f.value('../@id','nvarchar(15)')) as id,
        ISNULL(d.f.value('@userid','int'),d.f.value('../@userid','int')) as UserId,
        ISNULL(d.f.value('@modifiedon','datetime'),d.f.value('../@modifiedon','datetime')) as ModifiedOn,
        ISNULL(d.f.value('@modifiedby','int'),d.f.value('../@modifiedby','int')) as ModifiedBy,
        ISNULL(d.f.value('@modifiedip','nvarchar(15)'),d.f.value('../@modifiedip','nvarchar(15)')) as ModifiedIp,
        d.f.value('@detailid','int') as DetailId
FROM @XMLDOC.nodes('//*//*') as d(f)
```

Comment: I am getting the error "The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml" when I try to write your first code. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the datatype of xmldoc variable? It should be xml.

Comment: I have changed VARCHAR(MAX) to XML for input parameter of the sql stored procedure. But while executing the sp, I am getting "Invalid object name 'd' "

Comment: Well, I don't know about object named d, I suggest you to use new xml variable, like `declare @x xml select @x = cast(@xmldoc as xml)` then use `@x` in nodes. Or the most simple solution is to `set @xmldoc = case when charindex('detail',@xmldoc) >0 then @xmldoc else replace(@xmldoc,'</rec>','<detail /></rec>') end` that will add wmpty detail node, with this approach your OPENXML should work fine

Comment: I am trying to use OPENXML only. Here it is back to square one. The records are not coming for nodes that does not have child nodes. Could you please let me know what this charindex will do?

Comment: The @XMLDOC data is not getting replaced with new value. The charindex is failing here.

Comment: What is the code that I  have to write to insert <UserDetail ></UserDetail> for nodes that does not have child value?

Comment: Charindex find the first occurance of string in another string and outputs its position in integer. In your query I see `/root/rec/detail` based on this I suggested to add `<detail />` node. If it is called `userdetail` then use it like `<userdetail />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123097/discussion-between-cpk-2011-and-gofr1).

Comment: How the union works here? I am getting only Maintable records. The detail records are gone..

Comment: First takes all with /root/rec/details, second part with /root/rec.

Comment: Because I am using cursor, it is throwing error like cannot insert NULL to userid column. I need to tweak something here before inserting into #Temp table.

Comment: In that case just change `,NULL as Detailid` to `,somevalue as detailid`

Comment: I am not getting clear idea on where to use "..@" and "@" for variables declared for openxml

Comment: `../` means get the attribute value from next level. F.e. you got `/root/row/third` in OPENXML part. Then if you select `@something` it will take value of attribute named `something` from `third` part, if you use `../@something` it will get the value of attribute on `/row/` level.

Comment: Based on sample you share in chat I rewrite the query, now if it is no details - it will show `-1`. Check it out :)

Comment: I am not getting any records in the #temp table even though I am passing the xml to it.

Comment: After renaming the xml nodes in openxml Root, Rec and UserDetail with first letter as caps, I am getting all values as null and with detail id as -1 for all records

Comment: Have you tried to run this query apart from your SP with the xml you provided in chat? What was the result? I run it, and get output that I post to my answer.

Comment: XML is case sensitive, if you got `<root>` you should use `/root`, this is default. I guess you have some other options turned on or off, try to name attributes and passes as in your question with lower and upper cases for some letters.

Comment: The stored procedure is throwing error that column 'SomeColumn' does not exist. How to add column through OpenXml into #temp table.

Comment: Just add column in select above openxml.

Comment: It is throwing  error  Invalid column name 'SomeColumn' when I tried to add to in select above openxml

Comment: It is hard to say where error is with not seeing the code. F.e. `NULL as SomeColumn`

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If my answer was helpful, please upvote/accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please look into this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450015/openxml-with-left-join

Comment: I will take a look.