# OPENXML with Left Join

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have 2 tables called as "User" and "UserDetail" in SQL Server 2008. The main table "User" contains the following columns

```
UserId Int, 
UserDate DateTime, 
ModifiedBy Int
```

The "UserDetail" table contains the following  columns

```
UserId Int
,UserIdDetailId Int
,Amount Int
,Balance Int
```

The User table contains data as follows

```
 UserId UserDate    ModifiedBy
 101  "01-Jan-2016" 100
 102  "01-Feb-2016" 200
 103  "01-Mar-2016" 300
```

The UserDetail table contains data as

```
 UserId UserDetailId Amount Balance
 101  1001  10 2
 102  1002  20 4
```

For 3rd row of the User table, it does not have child records in  UserDetail table.

Now I want to retrieve records from both User and UserDetail table using sp

In front end asp.net, I frame the xml and pass it to sql sp.

```
<root>
<rec UserId="101" UserDate="8/22/2016 12:00:00 AM" ModifiedBy="8/22/2016 01:10:59 PM" userdetails="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserDetail]">
    <userdetail userdetailid="1001" amount="10" balance="2"  />
</rec>
<rec userid="102" userdate="8/22/2016 12:00:00 AM" modifiedby="8/22/2016 01:10:59 PM" userdetails="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserDetail]">
    <userdetail userdetailid="1001" amount="1=20" balance="4" />
</rec>
<rec userid="103" userdate="8/22/2016 12:00:00 AM" modifiedby="8/22/2016 01:10:59 PM" userdetails="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserDetail]" />
```

The openxml in sql sp is as follows

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (
SELECT  m.UserId,
    m.UserDate,
    m.ModifiedBy,
    COALESCE(det.UserDetailId, -1) as UserDetailId
FROM OPENXML(@i, '/Root/Rec', 1) WITH (
   ,UserId INT '@UserId'
   ,UserDate DATETIME '@UserDate'
   ,ModifiedBy INT '@ModifiedBy'
) as m
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  UserId,
        UserDetailId
FROM OPENXML(@i, '/Root/Rec/UserDetail', 1) WITH (
         UserId INT '@UserId'
        ,UserIdDetailId INT '@UserIdDetailId'
    ,Amount INT '@Amount'
    ,Balance INT '@Balance'
        )
) as det
ON m.UserId =det.UserId
```

) p

I want it to store in #temp table as follows

```
UserId UserDetailId  UserDate       ModifiedBy Amount Balance
101    1001          "01-Jan-2016"  100        10     2
102    1002          "01-Feb-2016"  200        20     4
103    1003          "01-Mar-2016"  300        NULL   NULL
```

I want to get 103 UserId also in this table with NULL for detail values

**My Question is how the OPENXML must be framed to get all the records from User and UserDetail tables using joins in OPENXML and I am not comfortable with OPENXML and its joins but somehow I want this to execute properly.**

Comment: Now I am getting all NULLs from detail table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first add `Amount` and `Balance`, so you can select this fields:

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (
    SELECT  m.UserId,
            m.UserDate,
            m.ModifiedBy,
            COALESCE(det.UserDetailId, -1) as UserDetailId,
            det.Amount,
            det.Balance
    FROM OPENXML(@i, '/Root/Rec', 1) WITH (
       UserId INT '@UserId',
       UserDate DATETIME '@UserDate',
       ModifiedBy INT '@ModifiedBy'
) as m
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  UserId,
        UserDetailId,
        Amount,
        Balance
FROM OPENXML(@i, '/Root/Rec/UserDetail', 1) WITH (
    UserId INT '../@UserId',
    userdetailid INT '../@UserDetailId',
    Amount INT '@Amount',
    Balance INT '@Balance'
    )
) as det
    ON m.UserId =det.UserId
) as p
```

As for your question, it is not clear, what output you want to get from this join.

Comment: I am getting nulls from UserDetail records in xml to #temp table

Comment: You need `../` in a `det` part. Changed answer. I already show you this query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427870/working-with-openxml/). In my answer I used `../` to take values of UserId from another level.

Comment: I am in a mess right now. Eg., With the current open xml, it is returning 40 rows totally. But the actual xml data contains 5 main elements and 4+4 child elements. 4 records for 1 header id and 4 records for other header id. Ideally I should get 8(detail)+3(header)rows =  11 rows. Some cross join is applied here.

Comment: In XML you posted in this question it has 3 parent and 2 child elements - this query returns 3 rows as expected. If XML will include 5 parent elements and 2 of them got 4 child elements then query should return 11 rows. It is LEFT JOIN - not CROSS JOIN. I bet it is something with your XML. Or - you add some modifications to query above.

Comment: The XML can  come with UserId and UserDetailId as zeros for header and detail rows. This is the reason I am getting 40 rows. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I can help you only tomorrow. I am on my way home right now. Try select distinct.

Comment: I am getting only 5 header rows if I use select distinct

Comment: Send me a part of your xml you have a problem with on my email (in profile) I will tale a look

Comment: I have mailed you. please check it.

Comment: I will check it soon.

Comment: `Userid = 0` everywhere that is why something like cross join occurs. You need to join on more then one `userid` field. Is there something unique? Maybe `modifiedOn`?

Comment: For the very first time, when we are inserting records it will be zeros. No, modifiedon is not unique. Instead of using openxml is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You have *denormalized* xml. `.nodes` will give you 13 rows on this sample.

Comment: I will always get 5 nodes with/without child nodes. Instead of zeros, if I pass 1,2,3,4 and 5 for UserIds, then will it work fine? I mean openxml.

Comment: Yes it will. This XML needs some unique id to work fine with your case

Comment: Could you please change the answer accordingly?

Comment: Thanks a lot @gofr1